# Is it safe to move object into itself

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any guarantees that `a` stays a valid object when I do `a = std::move(a)`? Should I correctly handle this case when implement move operator=? If so, are there any best practices to do it?

Comment: You should handle that case. It is sometimes not possible to predict if what you are moving is the object itself

Comment: You can do an explicit `if (this != &other)`, but this may not be the best implementation considering `a = std::move(a)` does not happen too often

Comment: @Ayxan That should probably be in an answer